# Memory allocation for the sorting functionalities in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I recently finished some code that loops through all my sheets in excel and then sorts them based on a particular column and the values within that column

the code is shown below:

```
Sub sortingByLooping()

    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Activate
        Set rngName = sht.Range("1:1").Find(What:="SOMENAME", MatchCase:=False)

        If Not rngName Is Nothing Then
            LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, rngName.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            On Error Resume Next
            Set emptyDates = sht.Range(rngDate, sht.Cells(LastRow, rngDate.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

        sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        If Not rngName Is Nothing Then
            sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rngName, _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End If
        sht.Sort.SetRange sht.Cells
        sht.Sort.Header = xlYes
        sht.Sort.MatchCase = False
        sht.Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        sht.Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
        sht.Sort.Apply

    Next sht

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

This code ofc works nicely (and I understand the whole "with" and "end with" block but I did it this way because I found it visually easier to read).

However I tried doing this beforehand:

sht.Sort.SetRange (sht.Cells)

I put parenthesis around the sht.cells when I set the Range and I got hit with an "Out of Memory" Error. I quickly changed it back to without parenthesis to correct the issue.

But now I want to know why I get this error when I put parenthesis around sht.cells and why I don't get this error when I don't put parenthesis around sht.cells? What is the memory issue surrounding this and are there any other risks that I should know about involving this particular line of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses around `(sht.Cells)` will *evaluate* the entire sheet to produce a 2-D array of the entire content (all one million-odd rows x 16k columns). That's not what you want to happen here.

Try using a more specific range on the sheet, and drop the parentheses.

Comment: Oh ok. I will definitely do that then. Thanks for the information. :)

Comment: @Gman you'll probably want to scan your code for redundant parentheses in procedure calls. Tip: in `DoSomething (foo)`, parens are part of the *parameter* syntax, whereas in `bar = DoSomething(foo)`, parens are part of the *argument list* syntax. Notice the lack of whitespace.